# Full body 6 times a week

Tags: strength, training, muscle-mass, muscle-gain, exercise-frequency

[The Norwegian frequency project](https://www.strongerbyscience.com/high-frequency-training-for-a-bigger-total-research-on-highly-trained-norwegian-powerlifters/) shows that training the same muscles 6 times a week granted double the strength gains than training 3 times a week.

Training 6 times a week showed also muscle growth at equal volume while the 3 times a week group experienced little to no hypertrophy during the study.

The weights used were around 75% of their one repetition maximum

The study was done for 15  weeks on 16 intermediate lifters and not novices.

My question is:

Is it wise to replicate it and how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The Norwegian frequency project shows that training the same muscles 6 times a week granted almost double to strength gains than training 3 times a week

Well, yes and no. It doesn't seem like they're training *more*. They're really training less, but more often, so it evens out.

As stated in the article; *Both groups did the exact same program. The only difference was that one group divided the volume in six sessions instead of three*

> The study was done for 15 weeks on 16 intermediate lifters and not novices

Intermediate seems like an understatement.

*Participants in the study had all trained continuously for competitive powerlifting for at least one year.  On top of that, they all competed in national Norwegian IPF affiliate powerlifting competitions within the last six months before the start of this experiment [...]*

These were competetive lifters. Meaning that after their workouts were done, they probably did nothing but go home to eat and rest.

> Is it wise to replicate it and how?

The more you train, the more recovery you'll need. And the first thing you might notice when attempting this, is chronic fatigue. That should tell you that you're overdoing it.

In terms of how you go about it, you just start. Your body will quickly let you know if you're doing it wrong. Constant fatigue means you're not getting enough recovery (food and sleep), which is what I personally would expect to be the primary brick wall. Other than that, you just need to go about it like you would any other program. With determination and focus. And with more focus on form than on grooming your ego with big weights.